# Android background location build in xamarin is taking forever

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, location, android-gps

So i am working with an app,which gets me current latitude,longitude,current speed etc,using GPS data,The app does not give me any errors and deploys successfully,and i am using my phone (Sony Xperia D 2005) to deploy it.
Anyway,it says "Waiting on location updates" but it is taking forever...
Sorry for all the lines of code I am going to paste,but I do not know where the problem is.
Here is my MainActivity.cs code: (I am new to xamarin and I do not know if this part of code is responsible for the problem,so if you need any additional code just let me know...)

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Locations;
using Location.Droid.Services;
using Android.Content.PM;

namespace Location.Droid
{
[Activity (Label = "LocationDroid", MainLauncher = true,
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | 
ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    readonly string logTag = "MainActivity";

    // make our labels
    TextView latText;
    TextView longText;
    TextView altText;
    TextView speedText;
    TextView bearText;
    TextView accText;

    #region Lifecycle

    //Lifecycle stages
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        Log.Debug (logTag, "OnCreate: Location app is becoming active");

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // This event fires when the ServiceConnection lets the client (our App class) know that
        // the Service is connected. We use this event to start updating the UI with location
        // updates from the Service
        App.Current.LocationServiceConnected += (object sender, ServiceConnectedEventArgs e) => {
            Log.Debug (logTag, "ServiceConnected Event Raised");
            // notifies us of location changes from the system
            App.Current.LocationService.LocationChanged += HandleLocationChanged;
            //notifies us of user changes to the location provider (ie the user disables or enables GPS)
            App.Current.LocationService.ProviderDisabled += HandleProviderDisabled;
            App.Current.LocationService.ProviderEnabled += HandleProviderEnabled;
            // notifies us of the changing status of a provider (ie GPS no longer available)
            App.Current.LocationService.StatusChanged += HandleStatusChanged;
        };

        latText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.lat);
        longText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.longx);
        altText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.alt);
        speedText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.speed);
        bearText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.bear);
        accText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.acc);

        altText.Text = "altitude";
        speedText.Text = "speed";
        bearText.Text = "bearing";
        accText.Text = "accuracy";

        // Start the location service:
        App.StartLocationService();
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "OnPause: Location app is moving to background");
        base.OnPause();
    }


    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "OnResume: Location app is moving into foreground");
        base.OnResume();
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy ()
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "OnDestroy: Location app is becoming inactive");
        base.OnDestroy ();

        // Stop the location service:
        App.StopLocationService();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Android Location Service methods

    ///<summary>
    /// Updates UI with location data
    /// </summary>
    public void HandleLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Android.Locations.Location location = e.Location;
        Log.Debug (logTag, "Foreground updating");

        // these events are on a background thread, need to update on the UI thread
        RunOnUiThread (() => {
            latText.Text = String.Format ("Latitude: {0}", location.Latitude);
            longText.Text = String.Format ("Longitude: {0}", location.Longitude);
            altText.Text = String.Format ("Altitude: {0}", location.Altitude);
            speedText.Text = String.Format ("Speed: {0}", location.Speed);
            accText.Text = String.Format ("Accuracy: {0}", location.Accuracy);
            bearText.Text = String.Format ("Bearing: {0}", location.Bearing);
        });

    }

    public void HandleProviderDisabled(object sender, ProviderDisabledEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "Location provider disabled event raised");
    }

    public void HandleProviderEnabled(object sender, ProviderEnabledEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "Location provider enabled event raised");
    }

    public void HandleStatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "Location status changed, event raised");
    }

    #endregion

}
```

}

Comment: make sure you take proper permissions please check https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/blob/master/BackgroundLocationDemo/location.Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should register both providers GPS and NETWORK.

```
LocMgr.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 2000, 0, this);
LocMgr.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NetworkProvider, 2000, 0, this);
```

The GPS provider works outside and NETWORK uses cell towers and wifi.

This [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) could help you how to optimize your code.